# cargar imágenes utilizando .map con reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Estoy llamando una mis imágenes por petición get pero no me las muestra las imagenes en mi .map, he intentado pero no he podido y si reviso mi petición get `"https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php"` trae todas la imágenes pero no me muestra nada en mi .map.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pine-hgjsdp?file=/src/App.js:213-269

code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [ruta, setRuta1] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet_imagenes1 = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php`)
      .then((res) => {
        setRuta1(res.data.ruta);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const imageNames = [ruta];

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet_imagenes1();
    }, 1000);

    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Galería de imágenes</h2>
      <div className="image-container">
        {imageNames.map((ruta, index) => (
          <img
            key={index}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            src={`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/fotos_anuncios/Imagenes/${ruta}`}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Se está actualizando el DOM con los elementos `<img>`? Qué tienen en el `src`?

Comment: el problema lo tengo en traer los datos en la petición get, asi coloque un console.log no me carga nada, pero si voy directamente a la ruta "https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php" me muestra los valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice 3 correcciones a tu código:

1. en la respuesta de axios, `res.data` es un array con objetos `{ruta: 'ruta.png'}`. Entonces se usa `setRuta1(res.data)`.
2. `ruta` ya es un array, por lo que `imageNames` se asigna como `const imageNames = ruta`.
3. en el `map` hay que deconstruir el objeto `ruta` y obtener el parámetro `ruta`. Tambien se puede usar la ruta como `key` para el elemento `img`.

El código final es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [ruta, setRuta1] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet_imagenes1 = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php`)
      .then((res) => {
        setRuta1(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const imageNames = ruta;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet_imagenes1();
    }, 1000);

    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Galería de imágenes</h2>
      <div className="image-container">
        {imageNames.map(({ruta}) => (
          <img
            key={ruta}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            src={`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/fotos_anuncios/Imagenes/${ruta}`}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

EDIT:

Considerando que el state `ruta` es un array, conviene cambiarlo a algo como:

```
const [listaRutas, setListaRutas] = useState([]);
```

Usar `listaRutas` directamente en el map, sin asignar una variable como `imageNames`:

```
listaRutas.map(({ruta}) => ( <img key={ruta} src={ruta} /> ))
```